# What does Emacs describe-key expect for input?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm in Emacs' `*scratch*` and I try

```
(describe-key "C-x C-f")
```

and I get back

```
"C - x SPC C - f is undefined"
```

Obviously, it doesn't recognize my `C-x C-f` shorthand. What does it expect? The documentation

> Display documentation of the function invoked by KEY. KEY can be any
>   kind of a key sequence; it can include keyboard events, mouse events,
>   and/or menu events.  When calling from a program, pass KEY as a string
>   or a vector.

doesn't elaborate on how that string or vector should be entered. What do I need to give it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify it as `(describe-key "\C-x\C-f")` or `(describe-key (kbd "C-x C-f"))`.

if you call `C-h f kbd`, you'll get:

> (kbd KEYS)
>
> Convert KEYS to the internal Emacs key representation. KEYS should be a string in the format returned by commands such as ‘C-h k’ (‘describe-key’).
>
> This is the same format used for saving keyboard macros (see ‘edmacro-mode’).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `kbd` was next on my "guess-and-test" list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the keys exactly. `"C-x C-f"` is a string consisting of the capital letter `C`, a dash, a lower case `x`, a space etc.: it's a *description* of what you press.

What you really press is `[24 6]` a vector of two chars (chars are represented as integers internally and 24 and 6 are the integers representing Control-x and Control-f resp). Another way to describe the vector of these two chars is as a string consisting of two chars: `"\C-x\C-f"` is one way, as Alex Ott points out in his answer; equivalently `"\x18\x6"` uses the hexadecimal values of 24 and 6 resp; or `"\030\006"` uses the octal values.

But we'd rather use the description "C-x C-f", so (as Alex Ott points out in his answer again) `kbd` translates from the description to the actual sequence of chars:

```
(kbd "C-x C-f") --> "^X^F"
```

which is actually two characters: Control-x and Control-f. The lisp printer uses the caret representation to indicate them, so it looks like four characters in between the quotes, but that is just how they appear: if you do the above in your `*scratch*` buffer, put the cursor on the left quote and press right arrow or `C-f` on them, you'll see that there are only two characters in between the quotes.

All of this and more is explained in the GNU Emacs Lisp manual, in the [Character Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html#Character-Type) section and its subsections.